# Is there a way replace index fast full scan with index range scan in Oracle execution plan?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

Here is a table *A*, and the primary keys of this table *A* are *A1_ID* and *A2_ID*.
And to avoid Table Full Scan of *PARENT_A1_ID*, an index was created.

```
/* The status of the index is as follows. */
A_PK_IDX          | UNIQUE    | A1_ID        | POSITION 1
A_PK_IDX          | UNIQUE    | A2_ID        | POSITION 2
PARENT_A1_ID_IDX  | NONUNIQUE | PARENT_A1_ID | POSITION 1
```

I execute that query in Oracle 11g.
In this execution plan, the index of *PARENT_A1_ID* and the primary key unique index of A perform index fast full scan, respectively.

```
SELECT A1_ID, A2_ID
FROM A
WHERE A2_ID = :A2_ID
START WITH A2_ID = :A2_ID AND
    A1_ID IN (
        SELECT A1_ID
        FROM A
        WHERE A2_ID = :A2_ID /* Conditional clause of the value I want */
            )
CONNECT BY PRIOR A1_ID = PARENT_A1_ID
```

I used hint to change FAST FULL SCAN to RANGE SCAN, but it didn't work.

How can i change this execution plan to RANGE SCAN?

Comment: Why do u feel the need to use hints to force a plan?. CBO would automatically take care of choosing good plans, if you have stats updated. what is the goal of your query

Comment: Generally better to explore why the optimizer chose a non-optimal index, but if you do that and find you still need the hint, check out the INDEX_RS_ASC hint

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2473614/11721472